# PayPal first redirect crash, second one redirect the user successfully

Tags: php, redirect, paypal, sdk, payment-gateway

these days, I implemented the **`PayPal-Account-Payment`** Payflow into my checkout. At this point everything works perfect. But sometimes I get an error when I try to redirect my customers to complete the order on paypal.com. When I refresh the page and submit all data again it works.

Here is my current **PHP**-Code:

```
$sdkConfig = array(
    "mode" => "LIVE"
);

$cred = new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(<**>, <**>, $sdkConfig);

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext($cred, 'Request'.time());
$apiContext->setConfig($sdkConfig);

$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("EUR");
$amount->setTotal($this->total);

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setDescription("Complete your order.");
$transaction->setAmount($this->amount);
$transaction->setItemList($this->itemList);

$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("https://example.com/order/success/");
$redirectUrls->setCancelUrl("https://example.com/order/cancel/");

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale");
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

$payment->create($apiContext);

$redirectUrl = $payment->links[1]["href"];

header("Location: ".$redirectUrl);
```

The error I receive sometimes at the first call:
`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PayPal\Api\Links as array in /htdocs/lib/Checkout.php on line 503`

Comment: Did you get the solution? I'm facing same problem .

Answer (score 0):

The paypal sample code does something different to get the url form the payment object:

```
$payment->create($apiContext);
$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

Guess your error has something todo with your direct access to payment->props.