# First PayPal redirect ends in error "Cannot use object of type ... as array"

Tags: php, redirect, paypal

We have a problem with our payment process regarding PayPal. Sometimes users get an error while being redirected to PayPal, most of the times not. Since it seems like it's not depending to the device they're using, I don't know exactly what to do. This problem comes up with every 3rd PayPal-Payment and if the customer sends the order form again it works on the 2nd or 3rd try.

We're using the PayPal PHP Manager by Jeremy Desvaux on a non-shopware based website. Means there is no framework, everything has been coded by our developer.

Is there anyone who speaks of himself as a PayPal-genius to help us out?

Error message when trying to pay with PayPal:

> **Fatal error**: Cannot use object of type PayPal\Api\Links as array in
>   .../Checkout.php on line 721

**The PHP-Code**

As you can see there is a comment in the first line which was a try of our developer to fix that issue by using the getApprovalLink method.

```
//$redirectUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
$redirectUrl = $payment->links[1]["href"];
$paymentID = $payment->id;
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO exampleTable VALUES (%d, '%s')", $this->exampleValue1, $exampleValue2);
$this->MainDB->query($sql);

header("Location: ".$redirectUrl);
exit;
break;
```

I also found a question which is probably about the same problem but hasn't got a helping answer.

[PayPal first redirect crash, second one redirect the user successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914553/paypal-first-redirect-crash-second-one-redirect-the-user-successfully)

**EDIT:**

This is the PayPal\Api\Links Class

```
<?php

namespace PayPal\Api;

use PayPal\Common\PayPalModel;

/**
 * Class Links
 *
 * 
 *
 * @package PayPal\Api
 *
 * @property string href
 * @property string rel
 * @property \PayPal\Api\HyperSchema targetSchema
 * @property string method
 * @property string enctype
 * @property \PayPal\Api\HyperSchema schema
 */
class Links extends PayPalModel
{
    /**
     * Sets Href
     *
     * @param string $href
     * 
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setHref($href)
    {
        $this->href = $href;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets Href
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHref()
    {
        return $this->href;
    }

    /**
     * Sets Rel
     *
     * @param string $rel
     * 
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRel($rel)
    {
        $this->rel = $rel;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets Rel
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRel()
    {
        return $this->rel;
    }

    /**
     * Sets TargetSchema
     *
     * @param \PayPal\Api\HyperSchema $targetSchema
     * 
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTargetSchema($targetSchema)
    {
        $this->targetSchema = $targetSchema;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets TargetSchema
     *
     * @return \PayPal\Api\HyperSchema
     */
    public function getTargetSchema()
    {
        return $this->targetSchema;
    }

    /**
     * Sets Method
     *
     * @param string $method
     * 
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMethod($method)
    {
        $this->method = $method;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets Method
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMethod()
    {
        return $this->method;
    }

    /**
     * Sets Enctype
     *
     * @param string $enctype
     * 
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setEnctype($enctype)
    {
        $this->enctype = $enctype;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets Enctype
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEnctype()
    {
        return $this->enctype;
    }

    /**
     * Sets Schema
     *
     * @param \PayPal\Api\HyperSchema $schema
     * 
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSchema($schema)
    {
        $this->schema = $schema;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets Schema
     *
     * @return \PayPal\Api\HyperSchema
     */
    public function getSchema()
    {
        return $this->schema;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Now that I used `$payment->links->getHref()` instead of `$payment->links[1]["href"]` I got the following error:

> **Fatal Error**: Call to a member function getHref() on a non-object in 
>   **../Checkout.php** on line **722**

That's weird because it seems like it's neither an object's method, nor an array.

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the Paypal\Api\Links class. You are trying to access links as an array when it is an object. This means either the Links property has been set incorrectly or you need to Treat it as an object and not an array.

Comment: Hi lewnelson, thank you for your message. I edited the post.

Comment: Going by the method names and what you would like to get from the class it looks like you should call the getHref() method. So instead of $payment->links[1]["href"] try $payment->links->getHref(). As long as the href property has been set then this should return the value you need. You might also need to use the getSchema which I would guess returns either http or https. But treating links as an object and not an array seems to be the issue here. Although it doesn't explain why it works sometimes and not others. Unless the code only gets run when certain conditions are met.

Comment: Thank you - we will try that and see if it works. But as you already mentioned, it's weird that it works on the second try, because the way of  targeting the href is still an array. `$redirectUrl = $payment->links[1]["href"];`

Comment: Now that I used `$payment->links->getHref()` instead of `$payment->links[1]["href"]` I get an error again. See my update (EDIT 2) on the post.